# Is there a good XML-based layout engine for iOS?

Tags: ios, xml

Storyboards and programmatic UIView creation are not particularly good at defining complicated layouts where some items, such as labels, may have dynamically defined heights. I want a simple XML-based layout engine, like a bare-bones implementation of HTML/CSS, that allows me to define a view using margins, padding, border etc. in the DRY manner to which I've been accustomed with HTML/CSS. Is there any open-source library out there that attempts this?

Comment: Read the iOS 6 docs and watch the WWDC videos.  ALthough really even the current struts/springs can do what you want.

Comment: It's not XML, it's better (for what the questioner wants to do).  In the end he'll probably end up using IB which is almost XML underneath.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner : XIBs are not "almost" XML, they *are* XML underneath ;) In fact, I once made an XSLT stylesheet to inject some external XML data into a XIB file for a particular project ;) _(unlike Terry I think XML is a very good tool and more importantly very very powerful once you know how to use it especially with xslt, xpath and more)_

Comment: Well they are technically plists.  There may be some deviation even though XML parsers can run onthme.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner : XIB files are not PLIST files, but are standard XML files. You can see that by opening a XIB in any text editor, you will find the XML prolog `<?xml ... ?>`, and also some tags like the `<archive>` root tag, that are not part of the PLIST DTD (the PLIST XML format is a subset of the XML format that simply conforms to a given DTD). So XIB files cannot even be expressed/converted to PLIST files (`plutil AnyXibFile.xib` will fail parsing). But they are always valid and well-formed XML files (`xmllint --valid AnyXibFile.xib` will always see the XIB file as a valid XML)

Comment: Besides, even if they were PLIST files, the XML PLIST format is also well-formed XML (and cannot have "some deviation" as you suggest). It can always be validated by `xmllint` as valid and well-formed. PLISTs just conforms to a given DTD ([this one actually](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd)) which reduces the subset of tags used in such files, but that does not allow them any "deviation". _And PLISTs that are not in XML format (but in the legacy ASCII format like `.strings` or `.xcodeproj` files, or the binary format) can be converted to XML using `plutil -convert xml1` anyway._

Comment: Ok, I'll buy that.  I'd just been told before they were not strictly XML.

Comment: You guys are missing the point: XAML is a *human-editable* xml-based layout language and despite some minor annoyances imposed by xml itself, its hierarchical nature is extremely well-suited for describing layouts. XIB on the other hand is far from human-editable. It's only using xml as a portable storage format. There is absolutely no consideration given to editing XIB files manually, so the fact that it's stored as xml is largely irrelevant to this discussion. I am with the poster: I want a way to describe interfaces in iOS using xml, because I personally hate Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3):

Y U NO wait for iOS6's AutoLayout feature? ;-)

This will allow you to define constraints and dynamic element heights, width, sizes, margins, paddings… with each other elements.

Comment: This guy SERIOUSLY needs to watch the video on the new layout features and abilities, complete with a custom layout language that is rather amazing.

Comment: Link to video or documentation?

Comment: Still under NDA so can't legally link to any doc but log in with your Apple developer account and watch [the videos here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) that talk about AutoLayout.

Comment: After the iOS6 release we can provide more clarity.  But the titles of  the WWDC videos you want are obvious.

Comment: Looks awesome, especially the visual format language. This might be a dumb question, but will I be able to compile an auto-layout app to run on iOS 5, or will my app only run on iOS 6?

Comment: Only iOS6 (but as OS updates are now delivered in OTA without the need to connect your iPhone to iTunes, I bet/hope the transition to the new OS will be quite massive)

Comment: _PS : If this answers your question, don't forget to accept the answer so that the question is tagged as resolved in SO_

Comment: I personally think it's worth pushing iOS6 only support going forward just because of this feature.  People can wallow in the past or get on the future train of awesomeness.

Comment: Totally agree. [Everyone should read the arguments of Matt Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/12/05/latest-version/) about this too :)

Comment: I'm now quite convinced autolayout is the worst thing ever conceived. Instead of simple bulletproof layout hierarchies, we now have a hodgepodge of mismatched disjoint and often conflicting constraints, each with their own priority and fuzzy logic. How on earth this is supposed to make layout easier I do. Not. Know.

Comment: I'm now quite convinced you didn't try Xcode5 which changes quite everything about how to manage auto layout. Xcode4 was a pain in the ass for using autolayout, placing its own constraints and all. Xcode5 is waayyyy more friendly and warns about conflicts if any, proposing a fixme and letting you choose the resolution needed.

Comment: Well here it is 2015 and we have Xcode 6 and AutoLayout is still the worst layout engine I've used. There's truly nothing like AutoLayout to make a simple task absurdly complicated, and take hours to solve the tiniest of layout issues. And for something called AUTO Layout, It's the most painstakingly manual system I've seen. You have to add a minimum of 4 constraints to every single object in your view. But be careful not to add too many or you will get conflicts! Nothing is automatic *except* the hidden system constraints that you can't see or change but which will still break your layout.

Comment: @devios You probably just don't use it properly then. For example adding all constraints to all your already-placed views in your XIB can be done in just one click with Xcode 6. I suggest you watch the various WWDC videos explaining AL, once you get the logic it works like a charm. I admit it may not be simple to understand for people not used to it at first, but once you get the logic, it will feel straightforward and pretty damn powerful, and now feels to me like it has way more sense than CSS (you probably have to click out of the CSS logic, maybe that's what blocks you?).

Answer (score 1):

Though it has so many awesome features like dynamic element heights, width, sizes, margins, paddings. I think AutoLayout is too hard to study, edit, merge, maintain.

You can check [BeeFramework](https://github.com/gavinkwoe/BeeFramework). It use xml layout as simple as Android does. It has an XML Interface Builder, you can see the UI when you are writing UI code

And the author is working on another project [samurai-native](https://github.com/hackers-painters/samurai-native). 
It uses Native code and CSS. I think it's more awesome than react-native.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case it is of interest to anyone - MarkupKit is an open-source project I created specifically to address this type of use case:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It allows you to build native iOS user interfaces using a human-readable XML markup language, similar to XAML or Android. It supports CSS-like styling via JSON-based "property templates" and provides a collection of `UIView` subclasses for simplifying autolayout.